# RefineryCMS - Blog page error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms

localhost:3000/blog throws the following error

```
 NoMethodError in Refinery/blog/posts#index

Showing C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/refinerycms-blog-2.0.4/app/views/refinery/blog/posts/index.html.erb where line #2 raised:

undefined method `content_for' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #2):

<% content_for :body_content_left do %>
 <%= raw @page.content_for(Refinery::Pages.default_parts.first.to_sym) if Refinery::Pages.default_parts.any? %>
  <% if @posts.any? %>
    <section id="blog_posts">
```

I executed rake db:seed command too as suggested by many on net but no luck.

Comment: Did you have change something in the controllers?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I did make changes in the controller so made changes for the blog controller too. Works now.